# Understadning concurrent GCD

Tags: ios, multithreading, asynchronous, gcdasyncsocket

The question is simple, but I failed to find a reasonable answer.
In a code like that

```
dispatch_queue_t background_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL);

dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
// do some stuff that takes a long time here...

    // follow up with some stuff on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Typically updating the UI on the main thread.
    });

});
```

The "background_queue" is a concurrent queue, so tasks inside it will start in order but may not finish in the same order. So we can have the block of updating UI being called before images being downloaded.
More clarification will be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the two GCD blocks will finish in order, because the outer block will only call the inner block after the long process has finished (to be more correct, it should probably be a `dispatch_sync` on the inner block)

This will guarantee the order, because the background thread will call the gcd block for the main thread just before its about to finish and only after the long task is complete

```
dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
// do some stuff that takes a long time here...

    // follow up with some stuff on the main queue
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //should be sync not async, but in practice should have little impact if nothing happens after this block
        // Typically updating the UI on the main thread.
    });
});
```

This will not, because both gcd blocks will be executed at the same time and wont wait for each other to finish

```
dispatch_async(background_queue, ^{
// do some stuff that takes a long time here...
});
// follow up with some stuff on the main queue
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Typically updating the UI on the main thread.
});
```

Comment: But here, background_queue is a concurrent queue so why should the UI Block wait for the long process?

Comment: If the UI block doesnt wait for the long process, it will try update the UI before you have got your data back (which is happening in the 2nd block of code i posted), so your UI wont show whatever your long process was supposed to get

Comment: So the UI block may be executed before data were retrieved, so how come when data arrived the UI block is updated (while it has been already executed before data arrived)?

Comment: Not sure if i follow, it could just be that the UI block just coincidentally ran after the block with the long task, but you are not guaranteed that will be the case always. Another scenario could be that you are calling these 2 blocks multiple times, in which case the ui would be updated, but in a really unintended way.

Comment: I think sync would not do the job, I think we should mark background_queue as serial because diff. of concurrent is that there is no guarantee which one will finish first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I cannot fully explain the GCD mechanism in this short answer, but I'll give a brief summary:

There are *serial* and *concurrent* queues:

- A serial queue works FIFO (First In - First Out).
- A concurrent queue guarantees no order in which tasks are finished or even started.

Then, there are two kinds to enqueue a work item: *async* and *sync*. This refers on how the call will return:

- An async call will return typically before the work item has been started or finished.
- A sync call will return after the work item has finished.

So for example, if you enqueue a workitem sync'ed to the current queue you are in, this will result in a deadlock.

But there is way more in GCD than just this, for example you could group work items and wait until all of them have finished, or you could start "high priority" work items that will be preferred.

Comment: In the example I attached, there is no guarantee that the UI block will run after the long process, is it?

Comment: If you _nest_ your dispatch calles, it will.

So if `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue() ...` is the last statement _within_ the `dispatch_async(background_queue...`-call, it is guaranteed that it will be called after all the work is done within the background queue.

Comment: That's weird, even if background_queue is concurrent? That violates the definition of concurrent queues!

Comment: the concurrency only takes effect if they are happening at the same time, if the one thread executes then at the end of its execution, launches another tread, then even though they are "concurrent" threads, they are still being manually executed one after another. The concurrency in this situation means that other things *can* happen at the same time as this thread, but manually calling another thread once one is finished has nothing to do with concurrency really, thats just order of execution

Comment: What you are talking about here is the definition of dispatch_sync not concurrent. That is, you launch something and controls back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You come back on the main queue **after** the long task has finished. 
I'll show you an example taken from an App I've worked on:

```
- (void)coinRequest {
    dispatch_queue_t coinsQueue = dispatch_queue_create("getUserCoins", NULL);
    dispatch_async(coinsQueue, ^{
        EMGetUserCoinsRequest* request = [EMGetUserCoinsRequest new];
        __weak typeof(self) _self = self;
        [self putCurrentRequest:request];
        request.suppressLoadingView = YES;
        [BackEnd() performRequest:request force:YES onSuccess:^(EMGetUserCoinsResponse *response) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                // Update the UI
                if (response.coins.coins != NULL) {
                    _self.coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", response.coins.coins];
                } else {
                    _self.coinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"];
                }
          });

        } onApplicativeError:NULL onEnvironmentError:NULL];
    });
}
```

As you can see I have a request asking for the user's coins. Since the UI must remain responsive, I use a bg queue. Once downloaded the info, in the "onSuccess" block I come back to the main thread in order to update the UI.

Comment: Your queue which downloads the data "coinsQueue", it it serial or concurrent?

Answer (score 0):

play in the playground!

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

import Foundation

var s0 = ""
var s1 = ""

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "cq", attributes: .concurrent)


let worker0 = { ()->() in
    for i in 0..<5000 {
        if (i % 1000) == 0 {
                print(i / 1000, terminator: "", to: &s0)
        }
    }
}

let worker1 = { ()->() in
    for i in 0..<5000 {
        if (i % 1000) == 0 {
                print(i / 1000, terminator: "", to: &s1)
        }
    }
}

queue.async(execute: {
    worker0()
    worker0()
    worker0()
    worker0()
    print(s0, " all workers0 were executed serialy")
})

let dg = DispatchGroup()

queue.async(group: dg, execute: worker1)
queue.async(group: dg, execute: worker1)
queue.async(group: dg, execute: worker1)
queue.async(group: dg, execute: worker1)

dg.wait()

print(s1, " workers1 were executed concurrently")
```

it will print something like

```
00101212323434041234  workers1 were executed concurently
01234012340123401234  all workers0 were executed serialy
```

**all code written in the execution block dispatched to any queue is executed "serially"**